# Can GitHub Pages render asciidoc?

Tags: markdown, github-pages, jekyll

GitHub repositories can render/preview asciidoc (.adoc) documents, apparently using asciidoctor.

But I can't seem to make pages served by GitHub Pages (GitHub's Jekyll-based service that serves repository documents under github.io) render my asciidoc documents.

Is it even possible?

Comment: I can't comment yet but here is a [request for GHPages adoc support](https://github.community/t/ghpages-jekyll-asciidoc-supported/166516) on the github community forums.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Jekyll does support rendering AsciiDoc via [a plugin](https://github.com/asciidoctor/jekyll-asciidoc), however this isn't part of the default GitHub Pages Jekyll setup.

GitHub lets you configure Jekyll plugins by [adding them to the _config.yml](https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-jekyll-plugins/) file. However jekyll-asciidoc isn't on the [list of supported plugins](https://pages.github.com/versions/) at this time.

You could try [submitting a request](https://github.com/github/pages-gem/blob/master/docs/CONTRIBUTING.md#how-to-suggest-a-feature-or-enhancement) to GitHub to add jekyll-asciidoc to the list of supported plugins, otherwise you'll have to run Jekyll yourself.

Comment: People, please submitt a request there on the gems issues :)

Comment: I create an issue https://github.com/github/pages-gem/issues/847